# Control ID rendering differently between environments

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a web application that works in our stage/test environment fine but once we moved it to our production environment something weird happens. All the control ids change.  For example a label went from `ctl00_cphMainContent_lblPetName` to `_ctl0_cphMainContent_lblPetName`. Why would this happen?  What could cause something like this to happen.  The only two differences I know of are the production environment has HTTPS and I've disabled debugging.

Comment: Its not related to vb.net or javascript, please remove this tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web.configs differ. Behaviour of the client ID generation depends on EnableLegacyRendering. Please review [xhtmlConformance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228268.aspx) element of your web.config. If it Legacy you will get "_ctl", if not - "ctl".

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what the problem was.  The root web.config had this set to legacy and this was inherited by our application that was in a sub folder.

Answer (score 4):

As the way the client id is generated may change between different versions of the framework, you should not rely on a specific pattern.

The `ClientID` and `UniqueID` properties should be used to determine the id and name that are generated for the html code.

The `ClientID` property contains the generated id, which you for example can use with the `document.getElementById` method in Javascript.

The `UniqueID` property contains the generated name, which you for example can use if you read a value posted with a form from the `Request.Form` collection.

Comment: This change was between 1.1 and 2.0 and probably will be in 4.0. I do not think that environments differ so much...

Comment: I don't think that this specific behavior will change in 4.0, as all versions of the framework since 2.0 are incremental.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have the server, which knows the control id, send it to the client-side JavaScript, which will use it.

The usual way to do this is something like this:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById(" <%= button1.ClientID %>");
```

I've always hated this, as, in effect, you're writing all of your JavaScript at runtime. Instead, what I like is to have a page (or control) emit a class containing all the control ids (or other server-side values) that it needs.

I'd post an example, but I haven't done this for a while, and don't have one with me. Basically, create a JavaScript class with members for every control ID you need, and register that with the page. Then register a startup script that does something like this:

```
myPage_Instance.btn1 = <%= button1.ClientID %>; // Better - do it in the codebehind
// more of the same
```

Your code can now be:

var btn1 = document.getElementById(myPage_Instance.btn1);